# Is it possible to take a picture without any interaction? (Android Studio, CameraX)

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, camera, android-camerax

I want my camera to take a picture by itself without any interaction.

More detailed: Im coding a Textdetector with the ML Kit. But the detection is not that good. Sometimes it is perfect, sometimes not. So my idea is to take a picture in a certain camera position. If this position is reached it takes a picture automatically and the result is always the same. That is my goal. Any ideas?

Comment: If by `without interaction`  you mean to trigger an image capture programmatically, you can use CameraX's [image capture use case](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/take-photo). When the detection is good, trigger the capture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cameraX analysis usecase, if processed frame is good then save it.